# How to connect my Python file to Excel to execute the output of my program to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, macos, pycharm

I've been trying to connect my Python file to Excel so that the data that is outputted by my Python program gets printed to my Excel file. I've tried adding the key values of my Python program to Excel then connect the two files via pandas but still did not work out for me.

I followed this YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svcv8uub0D0&t=357s

Here is my code

```
import PySimpleGUI

from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook


import pandas as pd

#wb = Workbook()
wb = load_workbook('/Users/safa/Desktop/بيان اسماء المستفيدين (أرشيف)/data2.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# Add color to window
PySimpleGUI.theme('DarkTeal1')

EXCEL_FILE = '/Users/safa/Desktop/بيان اسماء المستفيدين (أرشيف)/data2.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)

font_size = 100



layout = [



    [PySimpleGUI.Text("Please fill out the following fields:  " )],

    [PySimpleGUI.Text("The file number", size=(16, 1)), PySimpleGUI.InputText(key='The file number')],

    [PySimpleGUI.Text("Name", size=(16, 1)), PySimpleGUI.InputText(key='Name')],

    [PySimpleGUI.Text("Id number", size=(16, 1)), PySimpleGUI.InputText(key='Id number')],

    [PySimpleGUI.Text("Phone number", size=(16, 1)), PySimpleGUI.InputText(key='Phone number')],

    [PySimpleGUI.Text('The Commission: ', size=(16, 1)), PySimpleGUI.Combo(["doesn't deserve", "Marriage", "Housing", "broken"], key="The Commission")],

    #[PySimpleGUI.Text("Date (d/m/y): ", size=(15, 1),

    #[PySimpleGUI.Text('Date (d/m/y)', size=(15,1)), PySimpleGUI.Spin([i for i in range(0,13)],
                                                       #initial_value=0, key='date')],

    #[PySimpleGUI.Text('Date (d/m/y)', size=(15,1)), PySimpleGUI.Spin([i for i in range(0,13)],
                                                       #initial_value=0, key='date')],

    #[PySimpleGUI.Text('Date (d/m/y)', size=(15,1)), PySimpleGUI.Spin([i for i in range(0,13)],
                                                       #initial_value=0, key='date')],





    [PySimpleGUI.CalendarButton("Date", key='date1'),PySimpleGUI.InputText()],

    [PySimpleGUI.Text(' Convert to ', size=(16, 1)), PySimpleGUI.Combo(["doesn't deserve", "Marriage", "Housing", "broken"], key="Convert to")],

    [PySimpleGUI.CalendarButton("Date", key='date2'),PySimpleGUI.InputText()],





                            #PySimpleGUI.Checkbox("doesn't deserve", key="doesn't deserve"),

                            #PySimpleGUI.Checkbox("Marriage", key="Marriage"),

                            #PySimpleGUI.Checkbox("housing", key="housing")],

    [PySimpleGUI.Submit(), PySimpleGUI.Exit()]

]

window = PySimpleGUI.Window('Simple data entry form', layout) #, element_justification='center'

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')

    return None

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == PySimpleGUI.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    if event == 'Submit':
        df = df.concat(values, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
        PySimpleGUI.popup('Data has been saved')
        clear_input()


window.close()
```

I tried using openpyxl and panda and other types of modules but still nothing worked out for me

Comment: It may have been more useful for exposure to include the 'openpyxl' tag rather than say 'pycharm'

Answer (score 0):

- you can replace `concat` with `append` and its will work but this warning will appears in run window `FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.`
- another solution using `concat` function

```
values_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values, orient='index').T
df = pd.concat([df, values_df], ignore_index=True)
```

**explain code**
I created a new DataFrame from the dictionary values using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values, orient='index').T.`

The `from_dict` function is used to create a DataFrame from a dictionary.
The `orient` parameter is set to 'index' so that the dictionary keys are used as the index labels of the DataFrame.
The `.T` is used to transpose the resulting DataFrame so that the keys become columns.

Then, I used the `concat` function to concatenate the new DataFrame `values_df` with the existing DataFrame `df`, resulting in a new DataFrame.